# Memory Leaks profiler in Xcode - How reliable is it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, instruments

I have tried using the memory profiler in xCode.

It flags a number of objects as leaked object but when I open the history of the object, the last operation on that object is a release that sets the object reference's count to zero.

How reliable is the results shown in that tool ? are they potential memory leaks or confirmed ones ?

And if it is definitely a memory leak why is it happening when I have  the last reference count is zero ? could it be something wrong in the way I am configuring xCode's profiler (I just press cmd + i)?
Jamil

Comment: Did the Analyzer show anything? Maybe you can show some code of the objects that leak (where you instantiate and release them).

Comment: Analyzer(the static analysis tool) is fine I fixed all the issues raised by it.

Comment: The profiler is accurate, but difficult to interpret.

Comment: Sometimes it might be something within your object that is causing the leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I found the mistake !

I wasn't calling [super deallco] in the dealloc of the class of these instances

Answer (score 1):

The allocations tool is perfectly accurate if you have asked it to track retains and releases: it tracks them correctly. It also reports correctly the difference between how many of an object have existed during the previous history and how many exist right now.

The leaks tool is not always accurate: for example, in my experience it often misses leaks (I've never heard of its reporting a false positive but I suppose it's possible). Remember to allow enough time, though, since by default the leaks tool only takes a shot every 10 seconds. Also, use heapshots to hone in on the lifetime of objects.

Comment: Thanks @matt , the allocation tool shows the object as "live".

Comment: It maybe worth mentioning that the object shown as leaked it allocated and auto-released in a non-arc code (static library) to be then retained in an arc class